# What are constraints in static semantic?

Tags: constraints, dsl, semantics, mdsd

In regards to model driven software development.
As far as I know does the static semantic define the criteria for a model to be well-formed.

However I can't think of any real examples. So what are some real-world examples to help me better understand it?

Answer (score 0):

Static Semantics can indeed be regarded as 'the criteria for a model to be well-formed'. What those criteria are completely depends on the (modelling) language it is describing.

Static Semantics is closely related to *type-checking*. With the phrase 'Static Semantics' we usually mean a formal description of the criteria that make a program/model well-formed, while a type-checking is an executable implementation of such a description, which can be used to validate actual models.

To provide an example, imagine a language with a syntactic constructs `Expr.Plus = Expr "+" Expr`. A possible rule (written informally) validating the well-formedness could be:

If (`e1` is well-formed with type `Num()`) and (`e2` is well-formed with type `Num()`), then `Plus(e1, e2)` is well-formed with type `Num()`.

A more complex example of such a rule is: If (`c` is well-formed with type `Bool()`) and (`e1` is well-formed with type `T` (where T is a type variable, not a concrete type)) and (`e2` is well-formed with type `T`), then `If(c, e1, e2)` is well-typed with type `T`.

For a better introduction to this style of writing semantics (including formallish notation), see e.g. [these slides (especially from 35)](https://tudelft-in4303-2016.github.io/lectures/specification/static-analysis.html)

However, static semantics can be much broader than only checking addition expressions. Imagine a modelling language that models the heating installation of a building. A rule in its semantics could specify that a model is well-formed only if all valve ends are connected (so no leaks are possible).

Moreover, static semantics differs from a grammar by the fact that it usually includes *non-local/context-sensitive* constraints/checks (e.g. name resolution).

Finally static semantics is different from dynamic semantics in the way that the latter describes *how to compute a value from a (well-formed) model*.